# Event observer for category tree changed

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, catalog

I'm searching an observer launched after a category was changed by user in category tree (parent change for example).

The event `catalog_category_save_commit_after` is not fired on this particular user action.

Does anybody know such an event exists ?

Thanks !

P.S. : I already double-check event generated list and could not find anything on this theme.